# Using 5th overload of Html.DropDownList causes exception. (does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload..)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have a model with this property

```
public List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> ResponseTypes { get; set; }
```

And in my view I have this on my view which causes the error

error CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string

```
@Html.DropDownList("ResponseTypeId", "--Select Response Type--", question.ResponseTypes, new { @class = "form-control responseType", @id = "cbxType" })
```

I am trying to use the this overload

```
public IHtmlString DropDownList(string name, string defaultOption, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with this code.  I believe I have followed the overload properly.

I have also tried casting it.  I still doesn't work though.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ResponseTypeId", "--Select Response Type--", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)question.ResponseTypes, new { @class = "form-control responseType", @id = "cbxType" })
```

Comment: Isn't the overload.... Name, list, default entry?  put the select list before the default entry..... seems ok on my view.

Comment: you seem to be right.  But I don't know why the intellisense tells me that default goes before the listItems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using a method in the `System.Web.WebPages.Html` namespace, not the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace.

What you need to use is [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.String,System.Object%29) where the signature is

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    string optionLabel,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

so the code in your view will be

```
@Html.DropDownList("ResponseTypeId", question.ResponseTypes, "--Select Response Type--", new { @class = "form-control responseType", id = "cbxType" })
```

however I recommend you use the strongly typed

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ResponseTypeId, question.ResponseTypes, "--Select Response Type--", new { @class = "form-control responseType", id = "cbxType" })
```